# TikZ - Using coordinates in a domain

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a function up to the point of intersection with a line (point a in the example). Here's the code I am using but I gives errors on the "let" part.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Draw axes
\draw [<->] (0,10) node (yaxis) [left] {$x$} |- (10,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$y$};

% Draw the line
\draw [name path= line] (5,0) -- (5,8);

% Define the curve
\path  [name path= curve, domain=0.75:7]  plot (\x, {-1.8+8*pow(\x*0.26+0.6,-1)});

%Define intersection
\draw [name intersections={of=line and curve}] (intersection-1) coordinate (a) ;
\fill (a) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$A$};

%Draw the curve
\draw let \p1=(a) in [domain=0.75:\"What do I put in here?"]  plot (\x, {-1.8+8*pow(\x*0.26+0.6,-1)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you define the path `curve` **after** you refer to it

Comment: You have to load the tikz library `calc` to use `\let`. Then the syntax is `\draw let \p1=(a) in ...` ("in" is missing in your example). Note that `\x1` is a length in `pt`. So you have to divide it by the x-unit (default is 1cm).  Additionally your functions given in "Define the curve" and in "Draw the curve" are different.

Comment: Sorry. I messed up in creating the example. I edited the code with a new "wrong" version for which I now think I found a solution `\draw let \p1=(a) in [domain=0.75:\x1*0.0352777778]  plot (\x, {-1.8+8*pow(\x*0.26+0.6,-1)});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the trivial solution

```
\draw [domain=0.75:5] plot ...
```

is not of interest here and that the x-coordinate for the point is somehow "unknown".

I'd suggest you to use `declare function` to (well) declare your functions:

```
\tikzset{
  declare function={
  f(\x)=-1.8+8*pow(\x*0.26+0.6,-1);
  }
}
```

In this way you can now use the function name as many times as required and simply say `f(\x)` or `f(5)`, and so on.

When you say

```
\draw let \p1=(a) in ...
```

the x-coordinate `\x1` is in `pt` (points) so you need to convert it to the x-unit used in `tikzpicture`, which defaults to `1cm`; you can, however let PGF do the math for you:

```
\draw let \p1=(a) in 
  [domain=0.75:{\x1*(2.54/72.27)}]  plot (\x, {f(\x)});
```

The complete code (I removed packages that were not essential for the question):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{
  declare function={
  f(\x)=-1.8+8*pow(\x*0.26+0.6,-1);
  }
}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Draw axes
\draw [<->] (0,10) node (yaxis) [left] {$x$} |- (10,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$y$};

% Draw the line
\draw [name path= line] (5,0) -- (5,8);

% Define the curve
\path  [name path= curve, domain=0.75:7]  plot (\x,{f(\x)});

%Define intersection
\draw [name intersections={of=line and curve}] (intersection-1) coordinate (a) ;
\fill (a) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$A$};

%Draw the curve
\draw let \p1=(a) in [domain=0.75:{\x1*(2.54/72.27)}]  plot (\x, {f(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image]